# Why the intersection of infinite integers is $\{1\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Intersection of different sets mean that we will get only the elements that exist in each of them.

Then why intersection of all $\mathbb{Z}^+$ numbers will yield $\{1\}$?

It is clear that $1$ only exists once in the collection, and $2,3,4,\dots$ none of them match $1$, if we say we don't have duplicates.

$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \{1\}.
$$
$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{1,2,3,\ldots,i\} = \{1\}.
$$

Comment: Intersection is defined as an operation between sets. which sets exactly are you referring to by "all +Z numbers"?

Comment: @barakmanos ∞ (intersection of collection)i=1 {1,2,3,...,i}={ 1}.

Comment: I could ask what you mean by an infinite integer.  The term is meaningful in some contexts, and may have different meanings in different contexts.  However, I have notice some people saying things like "infinite integers" when they mean "infinitely many integers".  The former is an incorrect usage. $\qquad$

Comment: I formatted some of your post. Can't really figure out what you mean by "∞ (big intersection) i=1".

Comment: @MichaelHardy Infinitely many integers.

Comment: Intersection of collection.You know the big upside down U?

Comment: Also it will be helpful to have a tutorial on how to use this forum.

Comment: OK, I see @MichaelHardy has just fixed that one. Look for `LaTex` on your favorite search-engine.

Comment: So after @MichaelHardy's edit, your question is clear. Though, what exactly don't you understand about $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{1,2,3,\ldots,i\}=\{1\}$? The element $1$ is the only element which appears in every set.

Comment: so 2, 3,...don't represent numbers but the collection of numbers, i.e., 2  means {1,2}, , 3 means {1,2,3} ?It is only possible to get {1} if that is the case.

Comment: $2,3 \not\in A_1$.

Comment: Deleted my comment about ordinals, I misread the question. For the record, this question is very much *not* the same as the "intersection of infinite integers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \{1\} \\
& \{1,2\} \\
& \{1,2,3\} \\
& \{1,2,3,4\} \\
& \{1,2,3,4,5\} \\
& \qquad \vdots
\end{align}

The only thing that is a member of **all** of the sets above is $1$.

Comment: +1, but I think that "only" should also be in bold.

Comment: I see.I thought each number is representing numbers, but they are representing collection of numbers starting from 1.Many thanks.